# Best approach to display multiple images in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a JSP where I want to display images of vehicles from database. My entity class looks like this:

```
public class Vehicle implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id_vehicle")
    private int idVehicle;

    private String model;

    private String manufacturer;

    private byte[] image;

    @Transient
    private String encodedImage;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

One way to display all images in JSP looks like this this:

```html
<c:forEach items="${vehicles}" var="v">
    <img src="data:image/jpg;base64, <c:out value='${v.encodedImage}'/>"
        width="214" height="138" />
</c:forEach>
```

Which means, byte array is encoded to `String` and everything is passed to new `List`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import ba.spiderweb.carshop.dao.VehicleDao;
import ba.spiderweb.carshop.entity.Vehicle;
import ba.spiderweb.carshop.util.PageConverter;

@Service
@Transactional
public class VehicleServiceImpl implements VehicleService {

    @Autowired
    private VehicleDao vehicleDao;

    @Override
    public List<Vehicle> findAll() {
        List<Vehicle> finalList = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
        for (Vehicle v : vehicleDao.findAll()) {
            v.setEncodedImage(new String(Base64.encodeBase64(v.getImage())));
            finalList.add(v);
        }
        return finalList;
    }
}
```

Is there any better way to display multiple images in JSP instead of previously encoding byte array to `String` and recreating new `List` of vehicles? Possibly to encode byte array directly in JSP?

Comment: Why not simply have an `<img src="/images/vehicles/[vehicleId]"/>`, and the a servlet mapped to `/images/vehicles/[vehicleId]` which fetches the image bytes from the database and sends back in the response. The images could at least be cached by the browser.

Comment: @JBNizet Yes. That worked. I made a method which produces image jpeg value media type. But isn't that kind of bad idea since by loading each image one query will be executed (query which finds image by vehicles id)?

Comment: It all depends on the number of concurrent clients you need to support. But my guess is that, in the long run, you'll save bandwidth and time because car images probably don't change often, and with appropriate cache headers, browsers will cache the images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a servlet that maps urls to the image's file contents.

The html/jsp

```
<c:forEach items="${vehicles}" var="v">
   <img src="images/${v.idVehicle}"
    width="214" height="138" />
</c:forEach>
```

will call for images on urls `images/112`, `/images/333`... where those numbers are the vehicles ids.

A servlet will user this information to find the vehicle on a database and serve its image:

```
public class VehicleServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String path = req.getPathInfo();

    //gets what comes after "/" (I've not tested it)
    String strVehicleId = path.substring(path.indexOf('/'));

    int vehicleId = Integer.parseInt(strVehicleId);
    //finds the vehicle
    Vehicle v = vehicleDao.findByPrimaryKey(vehicleId);

    //sends the image
    resp.setContentType("image/jpg");
    BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(resp.getOutputStream());
    out.write(v.getImage());
    out.close();

}
```

And don't forget to [map this servlet](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/webapp/configureservlet.html#wp148787) to the "*/images/*" path on your `web.xml` configuration file.